# Vim Replace Split

Tags: vim, window

When making splits in vim, is there a quick way to make a split replace another split, rather than adding a new split?  This comes up when I code because I use `set autochdir`, in the following rather common scenario:

Say I have `/path1/to1/file1.txt` and `/path2/to2/file2.txt` open in side-by-side splits, and my cursor is currently in `file1`.  Now say I want to open `/path1/to1/file3.txt` alongside `file1`, but to avoid cluttering my window I want to open it in the split currently occupied by `file2`.  The only options I know of are either to switch to `file2`, hide it, then make another split, or switch to `file2` and open `file3` regularly, which makes `autochdir` useless.

Answer (score 2):

Windows are viewports through which you can view any buffer. This means that windows are not and can not be tied to any buffer or file.

What you actually want is to see `file3` instead of `file2` in that window. This is usually done in two steps:

```
<C-w>w                     " switch to the other window
:e /path1/to1/file3.txt    " open file3.txt
```

`set autochdir` sounds cool in theory but it makes navigation a nightmare — even in small projects — so, unless you have a very specific need, I'd suggest getting rid of that setting.

Answer (score 1):

Type `Ctrl-W w` to go to the other window, then type `:edit filename` to edit the other file.

If you want to be really quick, then instead of `:edit filename`, you can type `:e %<TAB>` and then some back space, so you can use the old file name as a template.

In fact, I don't think you still need `'autochdir'` now that you know of the `%<TAB>` trick. (It's a percent character followed by hitting the TAB key.)